# How to use two insert queries in same function in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have two insert queries in one table where two columns I am inserting from other table and one is I am inserting by own but in not working. Please help me.

```
INSERT INTO `g8_list_exec`(`g8_task_id`,`g8_tmpl_id`,`g8_chk_id`) 
SELECT `g8_rec_id`,`g8_tmpl_uid` FROM `g8_list_add_task` 
WHERE g8_tmpl_uid = 'oe_507','ik_862' 
AND 
INSERT INTO `g8_list_exec` (`g8_chk_id`) VALUES ('ik_862')
```

Comment: sql does't look right u r inserting 3 values but ur select query only select 2 wherei s the 3 value and you can run multiple queries if ur configuration allows that just separate them by ;

Comment: one is in last VALUES('ik_862')

Comment: Where r u selecting g8_chk_id which u r inserting into g8_list_exec ?

Comment: g8_chk_id I am inserting by own

Comment: do u want to insert using php??

Comment: what you want to do in actual ... ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO g8_list_exec (g8_task_id,g8_tmpl_id,g8_chk_id)
SELECT  g8_rec_id,g8_tmpl_uid,'ik_862'
FROM g8_list_add_task WHERE g8_tmpl_uid = 'oe_507';
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but "ik_862" is 'g8_chk_id' and I am inserting by own not fetching from "g8_list_add_task"

Comment: Yes. It will insert the value 'ik_862' and fetch the other 2 fields from g8_list_add_task.

Answer (score 0):

use below query it will work for you

INSERT INTO `g8_list_exec`(`g8_task_id`,`g8_tmpl_id`,`g8_chk_id`) SELECT `g8_rec_id`,`g8_tmpl_uid`,'ik_862' FROM `g8_list_add_task` WHERE g8_tmpl_uid = e_507','ik_862'

value which you want to insert manually place in select query only after all columns.